# How to Ignore a whole Mapped/Joined Model(Class) in Spring hibernate.

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have three tables. **tbl_vendor** and **tbl_category** tables are mapped using **@ManyToMany** relation.  When I am getting 'Vendors' under a particular 'Category' I am also getting 'Areas' because **tbl_vendor** and **tbl_area** are also mapped using **@ManyToMany**.

relations:

in tbl_vendor Model :

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "tbl_category_vendor", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "vendor_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")})
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();
....
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "tbl_area_vendor", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "vendor_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "area_id")})
    private Set<Area> areas = new HashSet<>();
```

in tbl_category Model :

```
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, mappedBy = "categories", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Vendor> vendors = new ArrayList<>();
```

in tbl_area Model :

```
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "areas", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Vendor> vendors = new ArrayList<>();
```

I have a **particular case** where I don't need this 'Area' with 'Vendor'. 
is there any way to ignore already mapped 'Area' from 'Vendor' using **JpaRepository** in some particular case ?

Comment: `FetchType.LAZY` is enough. The collection is not initialized (requested from DB) if you don't call the getter.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. 
But I found a cool library yesterday at https://github.com/monitorjbl/json-view. I just had to use 'exclude' on the time consuming field models to be removed. @JsonIgnore does the same trick but for that I need to use 'include' in my existing works. I just did not want to mess up existing project so I used the former one.